# Car won't start. No clicking noise

Tags: battery, jump-start

I tried everything I could,  even a jump start and nothing worked. When I tried to start it, it wasn't even making the clicking noise and the other car I used to jump start it, didn't struggle at all. I really hope it's nothing more than the battery but if it is something else I'd like to know.

Comment: If a jump didn't make a difference then it's unlikely to be just the battery I'm afraid. Can you give us more info on the car? Make/Model/Age ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you check the fuses?

Comment: Do the interior lights (overhead, dashboard, etc) turn on?